# Generate graphql schema based on the SQL Server 2014 database

Tags: sql-server-2014, graphql, asp.net-core-2.0, c#-5.0

I am in the process of developing an API using Graphql and asp.net core 2.Can anyone help me to know is there any nuget package or open source solution to generate schema based on the SQL Server 2014 database.

I see that there is a solution for java : https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sql-to-graphql](https://github.com/rexxars/sql-to-graphql) to generate GraphQL schemas and server based on SQL table structure. The only problem with this, is that the project is unmaintained.